# Excel VBA For Loop ends prematurely

Tags: excel, vba

Im currently trying to run some code that will open up a file, copy the contents, close and then open the next file.

Here is my code so far:

```
    Sub AddData()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set QD = Workbooks("Document " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY") & ".xlsx")
    
    For i = 6 To 0
        If i = 2 Or 3 Then
            GoTo Last
        Else
            Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\*************\Jeopardy Report " & Format(Date - i, "DD-MM-YY") & "AM .xlsm", local:=True
    
            Set JP = Workbooks("Jeopardy Report " & Format(Date - i, "DD-MM-YY") & "AM .xlsm")
    
            JP.Sheets("Document").Range("B2:B6").Copy
            QD.Sheets("Helpdesk").Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
            JP.Close
        End If
    
    Last:
    Next i
End Sub
```

The problem, is that the code gets to For i =6 to 0 and then skips straight to end sub.

If i remove the loop and just have i = 6, then the rest of the code works fine.

I have also tried to 1, rather than to 0, and still the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a negative step since the default is 1:

```
For i = 6 To 0 Step -1
```